# ClassPathResource.getFile() throws FileNotFoundException within WAR

Tags: java, spring, filenotfoundexception

ClassPathResource.getFile() throws FileNotFoundException. Here is the code snippet :

```
    ClassPathResource emsInitResource = new ClassPathResource("ems-init.properties");
    Properties props = loadProps(emsInitResource.getFile());
    logger.info("found 'ems-init.properties' on classpath, processing...");
    emsHome = props.getProperty("ems.home");
    if (emsHome != null) {
        logger.info("'ems.home' property initialized from 'ems-init.properties' as '" + emsHome + "'");
    }
    FilenameFilter ff = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("messages_") && name.endsWith(".properties");
        }
    };
    File[] messagePropsFiles = emsInitResource.getFile().getParentFile().listFiles(ff);
    String locales = "en";
    for (File f : messagePropsFiles) {
        int endIndex = f.getName().indexOf('.');
        String localeCode = f.getName().substring(9, endIndex);
        locales += "," + localeCode;
    }
    logger.info("locales available configured are '" + locales + "'");
    props.setProperty("ems.locales", locales);
```

And the exception is :

```
9:38:04,902 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ems-init.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:/home/tanmoy/JBoss/jboss-as-distribution-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/EMS.war/WEB-INF/classes/ems-init.properties
19:38:04,902 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:201)
19:38:04,902 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getFile(ClassPathResource.java:175)
19:38:04,902 INFO  [STDOUT]     at info.ems.config.EMSConfigurer.configureEMS(EMSConfigurer.java:45)
19:38:04,902 INFO  [STDOUT]     at info.ems.config.EMSConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(EMSConfigurer.java:34)
```

But in the WAR the /WEB-INF/classes/ems-init.properties is present. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: detailed explanation, you can ref to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ClassPathResource.getInputStream()` method to obtain an input stream and change the `loadProps` to load the properties from an InputStream (see the http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream) ).

You don't need to unpack the archive for this to work.

Comment: It worked. But I need to load other files from that path, as you can see in bottom of my code "File[] messagePropsFiles = emsInitResource.getFile().getParentFile().listFiles(ff)" how can I achive this?

Comment: You can do the same trick (with `getInputStream`) but in general with resources from archives (jar/war or generally speaking classpath) you can't do File.listFiles so you have to fix that at build time (generate a list of required resources and put it in a known classpath resource that you can access from inside the web application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your webapp container to unpack the WAR file.  A `File` cannot represent a member within an archive file.

Comment: @Tapas Bose - use the `jar` utility, or (better) configure your web container to unpack it automatically.  Tomcat does this by default.  What container are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the solution is :

```
    String emsHome = null;
    ClassPathResource emsInitResource = new ClassPathResource("ems-init.properties");
    Properties properties = loadProps(emsInitResource.getInputStream());
    logger.info("found 'ems-init.properties' on classpath, processing...");
    emsHome = properties.getProperty("ems.home");
    if (emsHome != null) {
        logger.info("'ems.home' property initialized from 'ems-init.properties' as '" + emsHome + "'");
    }
    //=================================================================================================
    FilenameFilter filenameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("messages_") && name.endsWith(".properties");
        }
    };
    URL emsInitUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ems-init.properties");
    emsInitUrl.openConnection();
    VirtualFile emsInitVirtualFile = (VirtualFile) emsInitUrl.getContent();
    File emsInitFile = emsInitVirtualFile.getPhysicalFile();        
    File[] messagePropertiesFiles = emsInitFile.getParentFile().listFiles(filenameFilter);
    String locales = "en";
    for (File file : messagePropertiesFiles) {
        int endIndex = file.getName().indexOf('.');
        String localeCode = file.getName().substring(9, endIndex);
        locales += "," + localeCode;
    }
    logger.info("locales available configured are '" + locales + "'");
    properties.setProperty("ems.locales", locales);
```

Comment: What is the package for VirtualFile?

Comment: @cosbor11 org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile