# Spring Boot uber JAR: cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system

Tags: java, spring-boot

I got following error after export Spring Boot version 1.5.7.RELEASE to runnable JAR. I don't use maven because security reasons, and I added all JARs in build path.

I run below command

```
java -jar mailer.jar
```

then I received error as you see in screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please post this as text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185137/spring-boot-resource-not-found-when-using-executeable-jar/26186317 might help you.

Comment: 2018-11-06 16:54:52.234  WARN 208 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [rsrc:com/atwa/base/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:com/atwa/base/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:com/atwa/base/

Comment: can you update project structure and error message in post

Comment: Please add line 22 (and surrounding lines) of your Applicaiton.java to the question.

Answer (score 8):

Because when your resource does not exist in packaged uber-jar, has problem with classpath. Use solution like this

```
String fuu = "";
ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("static/foo.txt");
try {
    byte[] binaryData = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(classPathResource.getInputStream());
    fuu = new String(binaryData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it's look greate , but i need to export runnable jar , that i can run with the following comman 
java -jar myJar.jar

i face the problem in screen shot

Comment: Hi @James, I need to create a new file while is dockerized, do you have any solution for that, I did a question on my account, if you want can you answer me

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
IOUtils.toString(new InputStreamReader(this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName.json")))

OR

new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("fileName.json", this.getClassLoader()).getInputStream())
```

Don't use **FileReader** or **File**

use **InputStreamReader**, **InputStream** etc

Comment: I used InputStreamReader as your answered here and it solved my issue. Thanks slot bro

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the application is trying to access a file through the AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile() (a couple of rows down in the stack trace) which is not possible from a runnable spring boot jar (it may work when running from an IDE).

Try using getInputStream() instead, see for example [this post](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/).