# How to get all files in directory in the classpath

Tags: spring-boot, classpath, embedded-resource

Is there a way using `ResourceLoader` to get a list of "sub resources" in a directory in the jar?

For example, given sources

```
src/main/resources/mydir/myfile1.txt
src/main/resources/mydir/myfile2.txt
```

and using

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

I can get to the directory

```
Resource dir = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:mydir")
dir.exists() // true
```

but not the files within the dir. If I could get the file, I could call `dir.getFile().listFiles()`, but

```
dir.getFile() // explodes with FileNotFoundException
```

But I can't find a way to get the "child" resources.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a [`ResourcePatternResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePatternResolver.html) to get all the resources that match a particular pattern. For example:

```
Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("/mydir/*.txt")
```

You can have a `ResourcePatternResolver` injected in the same way as `ResourceLoader`.

Comment: OK, but I don't know what I will find there. Perhaps `"/mydir/*"` with your code. I ended up getting it working with a `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`

Comment: What it the package for Resources? I could not find any class with that name that is part of Spring.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the answer. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Bohemian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) comment and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25873705/6346531), I used the following to get an input streams of all YAMLs under a directory and sub-directories in resources (Note that the path passed doesn't begin with `/`):

```java
private static Stream<InputStream> getInputStreamsFromClasspath(
        String path,
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver
) {
    try {
        return Arrays.stream(resolver.getResources("/" + path + "/**/*.yaml"))
                .filter(Resource::exists)
                .map(resource -> {
                    try {
                        return resource.getInputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to get definitions from directory {}", path, e);
        return Stream.of();
    }
}
```