# how to read folder from the resolurces files in spring boot, : Getting error while running from Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file

I am trying the below code where i reading files and executing from the resources folder.

```
File[] fileList = (new File(getClass().getResource("/jsonData").toURI())).listFiles();

for (File file : fileList) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.toString());
    }
}
```

Now when trying to make build in test env I am getting this error :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical

After investigation on internet I am using below code but no luck, (I need to read folder and its file.)

```
File[] fileList = (new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/geoJson").toString())).listFiles();
```

Comment: Spring!? I like [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791922/592355) ..leading (in comment) to [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html)

Comment: Everything inside a JAR file is *not* a file, and cannot be accessed using `File`, `FileInputStream`, etc. There are no official mechanisms to access directories in JAR files. Spring has some solutions like the one @xerx593 mentioned.

Comment: @xerx593 I am trying that answer but here in my case I have 4 files in `jsondata` folder which is placed in resoucres.

Comment: When there are only 4 files, and you know their name.. then just (4x) `@Value("classpath:/jsonData/foo.json")
Resource fooResource;` ?? ...the `File` will be (if) accessible via `fooResource.getFile()`...https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access

Comment: I am using the this way where exactly I am reading the file `Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filename.toString)));`