# How to get files from resources folder. Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-io, fileinputstream

I'm trying to unmarshal my xml file:

```
public Object convertFromXMLToObject(String xmlfile) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = null;
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(this.getClass().getResource("xmlToParse/companies.xml")));
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        return getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this errors:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null (No such file or directory)

Here is my structure:

[image]

Why I can't get files from resources folder? Thanks.

**Update.**

After refactoring,

URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/xmlToParse/companies.xml");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());

I can see an error more clearly:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/xmlToParse/companies.xml (No such file or directory)

It tries to find WEB-INF/classes/ 
I have added folder there, but still get this error :(

[image]

Comment: try `getResource("classpath:xmlToParse/companies.xml")`

Comment: Wont you need another "/" before xmlToParse

Comment: Code was update. Check it out, please.

Comment: any resolve? I face the same problem

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem trying to load some XML files into my test classes. If you use Spring, as one can suggest from your question, the easiest way is to use [org.springframework.core.io.Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) - the one [Raphael Rot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138523/raphael-roth)h already mentioned.

The code is really straight forward. Just declare a field of the type [org.springframework.core.io.Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) and annotate it with [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) - like that:

```
@Value(value = "classpath:xmlToParse/companies.xml")
private Resource companiesXml;
```

To obtain the needed InputStream, just call

```
companiesXml.getInputStream()
```

and you should be okay :)

But forgive me, I have to ask one thing: Why do you want to implement a XML parser with the help of Spring? There are plenty build in :) E.g. for web services there are very good solutions that marshall your XMLs into Java Objects and back...

Comment: I tried this, works locally but cannot be resolve when deploy to dev. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57466273/5777189

Comment: It doesn't work even locally

Answer (score 13):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("fileName").getFile());
```

Comment: This break as soon as you deploy this spring project into a jar. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20389255/5777189

Answer (score -2):

you are suppose to give an absolute path (so add a loading ´/´, where resource-folder is the root-folder):

```
public Object convertFromXMLToObject(String xmlfile) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = null;
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(this.getClass().getResource("/xmlToParse/companies.xml")));
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        return getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check whether the resources-folder is included in the deployment-assembly

Comment: I think, I have to bind this folder... Is there any easy way to do it?