# How to get the absolute path for the resources directory in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I'm trying to find a way to get the absolute path for the resources folder in my junit test.

My doubt **is not** get a file in the resources folder (I now how to do this) but get the path to the resources folder.

Per example, if my file in my resources folder have this structure:

```
/opt/project/view/api/target/classes/
/opt/project/view/api/target/classes/file_in_resources.txt
```

I would like to get the location `/opt/project/view/api/target/classes/` without use something ugly like:

```
URL location = this.getClass().getResource("/file_in_resources.txt");
String path = location.getPath();
String rightPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

The idea is have a method like `this.getClass().getResourcesPath()`, but this kind of method not exists.

How to do?

Comment: The answer is, don’t do it at all.  When you try to run your program from a .jar file, the resources will be inside the .jar file and will not be separate files at all.  Whatever you’re trying to do, there is another, better way to do it, one which doesn’t require converting resource locations to file paths.

Comment: @VGR, that should be an answer

Comment: @VGR If it's just for use in unit-tests it's not a problem?

Comment: @Tobb If the program is ever going to run from a .jar file, the unit tests need to be run against a .jar file.

Comment: What now? One does not usually run unit tests against jar files, the tests are not included.

Comment: @VGR, the tested class receive as parameter an absolute path to find a file (that I would like to put in the resources folder). This file in the production environment stay in the home folder of the user, it is a kind of "key". I would like to maintain this dummy key in my resources folder and pass the path for the tested class.

Comment: @Dherik then what are you asking? If all you need is the absolute path to a certain file, then you have already answered your own question.

Comment: @Tobb, I'm trying to find a better way. My answer no resolve the case when I don't have a file in the root of my resources. Per example, Instead of `file_in_resources.txt` I have only `somefolder/file_in_resources.txt`, the `lastIndexOf` strategy not work anymore.

Comment: Ok, so the file in used in the class you are testing could be at any depth inside the supplied path?

Comment: And is the problem that your current code is ugly, or that it doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327069/715269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a long philosophical discussion about the pro´s and con´s, if one should "have this question". But if you bump into it too like me, than this could be a way to go, if you want to do it with a **current Java style** (assumption: you´re *file_in_resources.txt* resides inside the appropriate and Unittest standard folder src/test/resources):

```
private String readFileFromResourcesAsString(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path filePath = Paths.get("./src/test/resources/yourCustomPathHere/" + fileName);
    return Files.lines(filePath).collect(Collectors.joining());        
}
```

If you really want to stick to the folder *view/api/target/classes/*, you could use that Paths.get-statement with a java.net.URI instead (like [Chetan Jadhav CD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6297496/chetan-jadhav-cd) already mentioned):

```
Paths.get(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
```

This solution makes use of the more recent Java-APIs around NIO.2 (see [oracle tutorials here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)) like

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

and some Java 8 stream API part to read the Files content into a String (you could change this part as you like :) ).

The

```
Paths.get(".")
```

is key here - it gives you the current working directory transparently whatever OS (Windows, Linux, MacOS) you´re using.

If you´re a Spring-User, the whole thing is even more easy! See [so answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39472514/4964553).

Comment: It is a terrible answer. The Paths/files/absolutepath technics is very different to getClass/getResource. The answer is NOT about the question.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get your intention here: This answer is far from lavishly thrown down, it tries to comprehensibly explain another - current Java style - solution. The question owner (besides accepting this as the best answer) only mentioned "a method like this.getClass().getResourcesPath()", but his code is far away from that - and there's simply not such a method. So providing a working solution doesn't seem so bad as an answer to me. And thus I also really don't get your downvote, this is just rude - sorry.

Comment: In Java there are several situations, for which operations for finding current dir or current resource dir, or current classloader dir or current plugin dir, or current dir in jar (repeat all above for jar) work differently. Any answer not exact about the theme, is useless. And obviously the question author wants the resource dir and you propose the current one. The fact that the author acknowledged your answer could mean he didn't see a better one. Or maybe, your spring reference worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your test class is located within the same resources folder, you could try:

```
URL location = TestClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String path = location.getPath();
String rightPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

If the resources folder isn't the same, you could navigate to it based on its relative location taking the location of the Test Class (obtained using the code above) as a reference point.

```
String adjustedPath = rightPath+"/resources";
```

Comment: The problem with this for me was, that class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() is just directing to c:/yourPathHere/yourprojectNameHere/target/classes

Comment: OP says in the first sentence of his issue description that he wants the *absolute path* of the resources folder. So the path on a Windows based machine would start from the root of the drive `C:/` in this case. The `rightPath` variable would point to the location where the TestClass is. However, we can modify this variable and adjust it knowing the relative location of the resources folder, for eg by truncating the `/target/classes` portion of it and appending `/resources` at the end of the truncated string. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Another terrible answer. The Paths/files/absolutepath technics is very different to getClass/getResource. The answer is NOT about the question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks Spring ClassUtils provides such method.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#classPackageAsResourcePath-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the context of a unit test, then it is no problem referencing a file directly, as you know where it is and it is not going anywhere. You can get the file url, then use `Path` to navigate upwards in the folder structure until you have the correct folder.

```
final URL location = this.getClass().getResource("/file_in_resources.txt");
final Path path = Paths.get(location.getPath());
final String folder = path.getParent() //getParent().getParent()...
                          .toString();
```