# Spring Boot load another file from app.properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties-file

I am new to Spring Boot. I have this `emailprop.properties` in `src/main/resource`:

```
       //your private key  
       mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey=classpath:/emailproperties/private.key.der
```

But I am getting the error as

> classpath:\email properties\private.key.der (The filename, directory
>   name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

How do I properly load this file?

***Update-1***

- my java code is 
  `dkimSigner = new DKIMSigner(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.signingdomain"), emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.selector"),
  emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey"));`
- its working as `"D:\\WorkShop\\MyDemoProj\\EmailService\\src\\main\\resources\\private.key.der"`Instead of `emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey")`

***Update-2***

- i have tried java code is 

  `String data = "";
  ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("private.key.der");
      try {
      byte[] bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(cpr.getInputStream());
              data = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      }
     dkimSigner = new DKIMSigner(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.signingdomain"),              emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.selector"),data);`
- Error is : **`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:private.key.der] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`**
- Tried Code is : 

  `ClassPathResource resource = new     ClassPathResource(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey"));
  File file = resource.getFile();
  String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();`
- Still same error..
- please update the answer..

Comment: first of all , how are you trying to load the file from the resources folder? have you tried [this one](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-classpath-spring-boot/) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407575/how-to-get-files-from-resources-folder-spring-framework) ??

Comment: `File file = new File(String.valueOf(this.getClass().getResource("classpath:/emailproperties/private.key.der")));`

Comment: @GingerHead thanks for replay. i have tried, but error as **EmailSmsService\class path resource [private.key.der] java.io.FileNotFoundException**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load this file runtime then you need to use `ResourceLoader` please have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) for the documentation - section 8.4.

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/emailproperties/private.key.der");
```

Now if you want to keep this exact path in properties file you can keep it there and then load it in your `Autowired` constructor/field like that:

```
@Value("${mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey}") String pathToPrivateKey
```

and then pass this to the resource loader.

Full example you can find [here](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-classpath-spring-boot/). I don't want to copy paste it.

Comment: My java code is : `dkimSigner = new DKIMSigner(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.signingdomain"), emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.selector"),     emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey"));`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is located here:

```
"D:\\WorkShop\\MyDemoProj\\EmailService\\src\\main\\resources\\private.key.der"
```

then it should be:

```
mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey=classpath:private.key.der
```

EDIT: 
I see now, you are using DKIMSigner, which expects file-path string,

Try changing your code like this:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey"));
File file = resource.getFile();
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
dkimSigner = new DKIMSigner(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.signingdomain"), emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.selector"),absolutePath
);
```

Comment: still getting error, if am **`System.out.println(emailProps.getProperty("mail.smtp.dkim.privatekey"))`**, here am printing **`class path resource [private.key.dev]`**

Comment: thanks, but still i got this error. **`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:private.key.der] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`**