# FileNotFoundException in spring boot jar but the file is present

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am getting FileNotFoundException while the file is clearly present in the jar. why is it so?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/serviceuser/project/coolApp/target/coolApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ssl_certs/mysslstore.jks (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112) ~[na:na]
```

However, I see the files packaged in jar.

`jar -tf coolApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep ssl`

[image]

**EDIT**
 I load the file as following

```
new FileInputStream(CoolApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("ssl_certs/mysslstore.jks").getFile())
```

Comment: The files inside the jar are not part of the traditional file path directory structure. You need to get the resource as a stream.

Comment: @Compass I loaded the file as above

Comment: I think this is certification issue.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri it is not certification issue. it is FileNotFoundException

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for Confirming.

Comment: you should put it only "mysslstore.jks" on FileInputStream

Comment: Does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception

Comment: @LalitAgarwal nope. I tried what is suggested there and it did not work either

Comment: Have you tried to use the spring `ClassPathResource` ?

Comment: Look at davidxxx's answer... it needs to be loaded as a stream when in a jar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here :

```
new FileInputStream(CoolApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("ssl_certs/mysslstore.jks").getFile());
```

`getFile()` is invoked on a `URL` included in a jar.
As a result, it provides a particular `File` object since that is not a `File` directly accessible in the filesystem.

And the [`URL` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)  confirms that (emphasis is mine) :

> Class URL represents a Uniform Resource Locator, a pointer to a
>   "resource" on the World Wide Web. **A resource can be something as
>   simple as a file or a directory, or it can be a reference to a more
>   complicated object, such as a query to a database or to a search
>   engine**.

So the `FileInputStream(File)` constructor cannot necessarily be able to open that "special" file :

> A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system.
>   What files are available depends on the host environment.

You can compare what you try to do with the following :

```
new FileInputStream("/Users/serviceuser/project/coolApp/target/coolApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ssl_certs/mysslstore.jks")
```

As you guessed, the file included in the jar(`mysslstore.jks`) could not be resolved by the OS filesystem.

Instead of, use `getResourceAsStream()` that returns an input stream. That input stream refers to the bytes sequence represented by the resource. In this way, the client code doesn't depend any longer on the way which the resource is stored.

```
InputStream is = CoolApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ssl_certs/mysslstore.jks"));
```

Comment: makes sense. Accepted the answer although yet to test it.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` is the key and it has been forgot so many times for people.

Comment: There is no constructor for new FileInputStream() that takes InputStream. There is no need to wrap `.getResourceAsStream` with FileInputStream. just `CoolApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ssl_certs/mysslstore.jks")` is sufficient

Comment: @brain storm In fact it would make no sense at all :) Thanks I fixed the last line.

Comment: In this case, CoolApp would be the name of the main class of the Spring project...right?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in spring boot and I have tried many things like bellow but nun of them is working. thease all are working locally but  It is giving `FileNotFoundException` in dev environmnet because when we build a JAR, the resources get placed into the root directory of the packaged artifacts and our downloaded files I placed inside resource folder.

```java
//Method 1: Working solution for jars
    InputStream stram=getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(File.separator+"database.properties");
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(File.separator+"database.properties");
    
    Only thing which worked is ResourceLoader. Need to Autowire it:
        @Autowired
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + File.separatorChar + NPIConstants.VAR_FOLDER
                    + File.separatorChar + NPIConstants.TPSPIDsBUCKET_FILENAME);
            InputStreamResource isResource = new InputStreamResource(resource.getInputStream());
        
//Method 1: Not Working solution for jars
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream("database.properties");
    System.out.println(is.available());
            
//Method 2:  Not Working solution for jars
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("database.properties");
    InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
    
//Method 3: Not Working solution for jars
    File file = new File("resources/database.properties");
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    
//Method 4: Not Working solution for jars
    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("database.properties").getFile());
    
//Method 5: Not Working solution for jars
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    classLoader.getResource("database.properties");
    String path  = classLoader.getResource("database.properties").getPath();
```

Comment: No, resource loader doesn't work for jars either. Also please fix the formatting if possible.

Answer (score -4):

Files like this need to be in the resources directory.

Comment: in sourcecode, it is in resources. what I show above is the jar contents.

Comment: And they need to be accessed as resources, not as files.