# Copying zip File from application Resource folder to target using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been facing an issues while copying the zip file(contains couple of RPM files) from **resource folder to target folder** using **Spring boot application**. It does create the zip file on target folder path but it doesn't have all the files inside and the one's created are corrupted. Please see attachment

I had gone through couple of links but seems solution is not working perfectly

1. [How to get files from resources folder. Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407575/how-to-get-files-from-resources-folder-spring-framework)
2. [Read file from resources folder in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot)

**Snapshot of Resource zip Folder**
[[image: **Resource Path:**[2]]

**Snapshot of files inside zip Folder**
**[image: package.zip files list]**

**Code:**

```
 ClassPathResource cpr = null;
            cpr = new ClassPathResource("/16.00/package.zip");
            try {
                InputStream data = cpr.getInputStream();
                File targetFile = new File("C:\\package.zip");
                java.nio.file.Files.copy(
                        data, 
                          targetFile.toPath(), 
                          StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        IOUtils.closeQuietly(data);
                log.info("w"+data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The above code create a zip file on target folder but its corrupted.When i try to open the file it gives me following error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you think your code would produce a Zip file, you're just copying files into a file, which would just produce random bytes.  You need to specifically create Zip files and ZipStreams.  Here's a utility mehtod...

```
public static void addToZipFile(String zipFile, String[] filesToZip) throws Exception 
{
    // Create a buffer for reading the files
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    // Create the ZIP file
    String outFilename = zipFile;
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));

    // Compress the files
    for (int i = 0; i < filesToZip.length; i++) 
    {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filesToZip[i]);

        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(FilenameUtils.getName(filesToZip[i])));

        // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) 
        {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        // Complete the entry
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    }

    // Complete the ZIP file
    out.close();

}
```

Comment: This part of mine is already working. i can add files in zip using above code. question is : How can i read zip file from resource folder and move into any target folder using spring boot?