# Spring MVC file not found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC. In my controller I called a function from MyClass

```
MyClass{
  public static void readFile(){
    File file = new FileReader("myPath/myFile.txt");
    ...
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    readFile();//No problem
  }
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String readFile(Locale locale, Model model) {
    MyClass.readFile();//File not found exception
    ....
  }
}
```

The reading works when I test it in the main() of MyClass, but when I run the project on server and visit "/url", I got this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myPath/myFile.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

How do I specify the path in the controller?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe this could be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371748/spring-boot-access-static-resources-missing-scr-main-resources

Answer (score 0):

What is the working directory on the server?  From that directory, does the relative path to the file ("myPath/myFile.txt") exist on the server?

Assuming you only need to read myFile.txt, then typically myFile.txt would be included within the WAR, and read via [getResourceAsStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Resource` implementations in Spring. Spring will determine which type of Resource to use, for example if your file is in the classpath Spring will create a `ClasspathResource` or it points to a file it will create a `FileResource`. If you are using Spring 4. Try something like

```
@Value("file:///myPath/myFile.txt")
Resource myFile;
```

Have a look at this [Spring Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) docs

Answer (score 0):

because this is not absolutely path. Program will find files under Working Directory
you can add this into first program and the second one

```
   System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
    System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

You will see the difference.