# Spring Boot Unable to find File using ClassPathResource

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot. I am trying to parse an excel file stored locally within the project using Apache POI library. My directory structure is like so:

- src

  - main

    - java

      - com.app

        - controllers
        - models
        - repositories     <- I am calling from here
    - resources

      - static

        - Test.xlsx     <- I'm trying to access this

---

```
File excel = new ClassPathResource("Test.xlsx").getFile();

File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("src/main/resources/static/test.xlsx").getFile());
```

I have tried both of the above ways to access the file, and I have tried many variations of paths to the file, but nothing has worked. I do not get build errors or runtime errors, the file is simply not found and when I attempt to invoke the method I get a NullPointerException on that line.

Comment: suppose this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371748/spring-boot-access-static-resources-missing-scr-main-resources) may have the solution for you.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I have tried the proposed solution from that post but it is still not found

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct in your case would be

```
new ClassPathResource("/static/Test.xlsx").getFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

supoose you just override the addResourceHandlers method of `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

this is a blog post about Spring resources - [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

Take look at spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) for more details.

Comment: I'm not using Spring MVC I just have simple setup. Can this also be achieved by adding "spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**" to the application.properties?