# Returning a image with ServletContext

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to return a image with ServletContext but I get a 500 error and the console says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>         at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146)
>         at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)
>         at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)
>         at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)
>         at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:721)

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ImageConfiguration {

    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter() {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        arrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedMediaTypes());
        return arrayHttpMessageConverter;
    }

    private List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        list.add(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        list.add(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        list.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class ImageService {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    public byte[] getRankImage (String id) throws IOException {

        byte[] b;

            InputStream in;


        if (id.equals("0")) {
            in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("images/level-0.png");
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

restful service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/level/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        byte[] imageBytes;

        try {
            imageBytes = imageService.getRankImage(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(imageBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The images are located in `resources -> images -> {image_name}` when I look in the war file I confirm that they are in there. I am not sure if I am doing this wrong or I need to handle the path differently.

---------Update 1-------

I took the war file and deployed it manually in apache and this is the output:
[image]

Comment: So, `InputStream` instance `in` coming as null here?

Answer (score 0):

In `ImageService` class, you autowired `ServletContext` instance.

Spring container will not autowire `servletContext` as it is not a spring bean. `ServletContext` is from `javax.servlet` package.

You can inject the instance using setter method as shown below.

```
@Service
public class ImageService implements ServletContextAware{

     private ServletContext context;

     public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.context = servletContext;
     }

     // use `context` object to get the image and pass to IOUtils.toByteArray method
}
```

By implementing [ServletContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) interface, Spring will inject it for you.

Ideally, we shouldn't be injecting `ServletContext` instance outside the `Controller` layer. Here, we are injecting in Service layer which isn't the recommended approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `java.lang.NullpointerEception: null` yes same error. The files are located in `recources -> images -> {image_name}`

Comment: `if (id.equals("0")) {
            in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("images/level-0.png");
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        }`

Comment: Don't think it would work with spring-boot. I think servlet context resources work with `war`. I think they work in `/src/main/webapp` rather `/src/main/resources`. Are you running it as a jar?

Comment: Have you verified whether the images are located in the same location inside jar? Have you exploded and checked?

Comment: I just updated the post. I am not seeing my images as I would typically see in a war file. The format looks off - I am using spring boots internal apache server

Comment: Any reason you are using resourceloader? Since, they are images, why don't you consider loading the images from external filesystem using file api?

Comment: Going off this post: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data

Comment: In the above link, they are fetching from `WEB-INF/*` which is apt for MVC projects. I would suggest you to load from external filesystem rather bulging your war.. :) Good luck!

Comment: is byte array which is returned from getRankImage empty or not? if it is empty you will know that you do not have correct path. I think this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371748/spring-boot-access-static-resources-missing-scr-main-resources

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.xyzws.com/servletfaq/how-to-use-servletcontextgetresourceasstreamjavalangstring-path/18 , the line

```
in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("images/level-0.png");
```

should have a / before the *images*, and the path should be relative to the current context root (parent of WEB-INF).

Comment: I have tried to add `/` and placed the images in `webapps` too and it still returns null.

Comment: So your image is at WEB-INF/../images/?

Comment: @Drew1208, did that (with the double-dots) work?  If so, please accept the answer.