# Spring Boot can find resource file, but Java class fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, java-8

I am working on a project where in one class I need to load `json` file `src/main/resources`.

```
src/ 
   main/java/FirebaseTokenVerifier
   main/resources/staging_firebase.json
```

The class `ForebaseTokenVerifier` loads this `JSON` file in constructor as

```
@Component
public class FirebaseTokenVerifier implements TokenVerifier {

  private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

  // TODO (hhimanshu): resourceFile and DatabaseURL are hardcoded, this should be picked by external file
  // or should be picked up conditionally based on environment
  public FirebaseTokenVerifier() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    final String resourceName = "staging_firebase.json";
    System.out.println("Getting Resource: " + resourceName);
    Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(resourceName).toURI());

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(path.toFile());
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://staging-myapp.firebaseio.com")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp defaultApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(defaultApp);

  }
 /// more things here .....
}
```

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run`, I see that the `json` file is loaded correctly as

```
2017-07-26 15:57:33.611  INFO 49104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-26 15:57:33.611  INFO 49104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1424 ms
Getting Resource: staging_firebase.json
2017-07-26 15:57:33.799  INFO 49104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
```

and everything works fine. I then, try to do the following

```
 mvn clean package; java -jar target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But this fails on runtime

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firebaseTokenVerifier' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/myapp-core/targ
    et/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/myapp/api/auth/FirebaseTokenVerifier.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationEx
    ception: Failed to instantiate [com.myapp.api.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifier]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.myapp.api.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifier]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointe
    rException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.myapp.api.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifier.<init>(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:31) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

It fails on `L31` which is

```
Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(resourceName).toURI());
```

I also confirm that the `json` file is present in the jar file as

```
✗ jar -tvf target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar| grep json
  2355 Wed Jul 26 16:00:44 NZST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/staging_firebase.json
 64952 Tue Jan 07 19:29:24 NZDT 2014 BOOT-INF/lib/json-20140107.jar
```

What is going wrong here? and how come `Spring-Boot` is able to resolve this path correctly?

**UPDATE**
After looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372773/379235, I changed my code to look like

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(new ClassPathResource(resourceName).getFile());
```

and it fails now saying

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firebaseTokenVerifier' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/myapp-core/target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/myapp/api/auth/FirebaseTokenVerifier.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationEx
    ception: Failed to instantiate [com.myapp.api.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifier]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [staging_firebase.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/myapp-core/target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOO
    T-INF/classes!/staging_firebase.json
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.myapp.api.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifier]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [staging_firebase.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/penn
    ytrak-core/target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/staging_firebase.json
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [staging_firebase.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/myapp-core/target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/staging_firebase.json
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:215) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.myapp.api.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifier.<init>(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:34) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Even though I can see that in the jar file

```
✗ jar -tvf target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar| grep json
  2355 Wed Jul 26 16:54:02 NZST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/staging_firebase.json
 64952 Tue Jan 07 19:29:24 NZDT 2014 BOOT-INF/lib/json-20140107.jar
```

Comment: Try using getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)

Comment: Thanks, I get `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:/Users/Harit.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/myapp-core/target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/staging_firebase.json (No such file or directory)`

Comment: OK, try this: resource.getInputStream() - read more here: https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/ should work AFAIK

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [staging_firebase.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/Hari
t.Himanshu/bl/sources/idea/myapp-core/target/myapp-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/staging_firebase.json`

Answer (score 1):

```
cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system
```

This is pretty explicit. You're trying to access it as file, when it is NOT a file but a resource embedded in the JAR.

Research `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience:

| Access mode | File in the same project | File in a jar | File in a jar with spring-boot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Path.of("src/main/resources/staging_firebase.json")` | **works** | does not work | does not work |
| `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() .getResourceAsStream("staging_firebase.json")` | **works** | **works** | does not work |
| `MyClass.class.getClassLoader() .getResourceAsStream("staging_firebase.json")` (`MyClass` is a class in the same library as the `staging_firebase.json` file) | **works** | **works** | **works** |

For spring-boot, my guess is that Spring uses a custom system class loader that is not related with the classloader common to `MyClass` and `staging_firebase.json`.