# Java Jar (created by Spring Boot Maven Plugin) is not able to locate files in src/main/resources

Tags: java, spring-boot

I saw [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder) and that is for that is programmatically getting the resource and I don't face any issue when I run the code locally.

I am facing a weird issue. I have a Runner file which looks at the files present at - `src/main/resources`.  Runner works fine if I run it standalone, but when I make a jar and try to run the jar it could not locate the files in `src/main/resources`.

[image: Jar Structure- made by Springboot]

[image: extent-confif.xml is present in the jar]

[image: Project Structure]

When I run

```
java -jar Java_Project.jar
```

then I get error:

```
Jul 05, 2022 10:17:17 AM com.aventstack.extentreports.config.external.XmlConfigLoader createStream             
SEVERE: src\main\resources\extent-config.xml                                                                   
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\extent-config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Build section of POM.xml looks like

```xml
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>test</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include></include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
          <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>
              Runner
            </mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Any solution or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: When you package your application in a JAR file, resource files, such as `extent-config.xml` need to be in the JAR file and not in folder `src\main\resources`.

Comment: @Abra : Yes correct. That's why if you see the second screenshot extent-config.xml can be see in BOOT-INF\classes folder.
Did I put it at wrong place? if you see POM.xml I tried to add resources in build section also

Comment: I don't know if you put it in the wrong place but the path to the file, in the JAR, cannot be `src\main\resources` if it is in `classes` subfolder of `BOOT-INF`. Does this help? [Spring Boot access static resources missing scr/main/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371748/spring-boot-access-static-resources-missing-scr-main-resources)

Comment: You should not resolve resource as files, nor should you resolve them as `src/main/resources`, when resources are packaged, the contents of `src/main/resources` is put in the classpath root (so `src/main/resources/extent-config.xml` should be loaded with `someClassOrClassloader.getResourceAsStream("/extent-config.xml")`, or one of the mechanism of Spring to load resources. You should **not** use file system access, because those files are inside the JAR, not on the file system.