# Access resources in subproject Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources

I have 1 root project and 3 modules(api,model,storage) in it. 
Here is the project structure:

```
**root**
--**api**
----src
------main
--------java
----------Application.java
--------resources
----------data.csv
----build.gradle
--**model**
----src
----build.gradle
--**storage**
----src
----build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

In my Application.java I'm trying to read CSV file from the resources:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @EnableSolrRepositories
    public class MyApp{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            SpringApplication.run(MatMatchApp.class);
            ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("classpath:data.csv");
            String path =res.getPath();
            File csv = new File(path);
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(csv);
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting an exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```

I was trying the following code as well:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("data.csv").getFile());
```

Any suggestions how can I read the file from resources in my API project?

**SOLVED**
This code works fine:

```
InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("/example.csv").getInputStream();
```

For more details check this answer:[Classpath resource not found when running as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer helped me to solve the problem:
[Classpath resource not found when running as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar)

resource.getFile() expects the resource itself to be available on the file system, i.e. it can't be nested inside a jar file.
You need to use InputStream instead:

```
InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("/example.csv").getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested a normal project you can see here [spring-boot-resource-access](https://gitlab.com/cavva/spring-boot-resource-access)

You may miss that `/` in front of your file.

```
ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("classpath:/data.csv");
```

or

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/data.csv").getFile());
```

UPDATE

---

Testing the application you have to find ClassPath from an instanced class like `ConfigurableApplicationContext` for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    File csv = new File(context.getClass().getResource("/application.properties").toURI());
    System.out.println(csv.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(String.format("does file exists? %s", csv.exists()));
}
```