# Spring boot Resource getFile() is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

In my spring boot project I am trying to load an xml file located in resources folder. If I try loading file with

```
Resource resource= resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + filepath);
File tempFile = resource.getFile();
```

I get following error in docker container where as the file is present in BOOT-INF\classes folder in jar file (packing type is jar)

```
Exception occur while generating mock sso response java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mock_sso_response.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/polst-webapp-2.1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/mock_sso_response.xml
```

However using getInputStream works.

```
Resource resource= resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + MOCK_SSO_RESPONSE_FILE);
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

It would be really helpful if someone could share the reason behind this and also is there any better/alternate way to load xml files in spring boot. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What do you pass in variable filepath and in MOCK_SSO_RESPONSE_FILE ? Just to double confirm its having the same value.

Comment: take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar). In short, ```resource.getFile()``` expects the resource on the filesystem.

Comment: @Victor Thank you this answers my questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classpath resource not found when running as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar)

Answer (score 2):

From the Spring [Resource JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#getFile--)

> Throws:
>   FileNotFoundException - if the resource cannot be resolved as absolute file path, i.e. if the resource is not available in a file system

So it seems the implementation of Resource just doesn't support the usage of getFile(). Usually you want to check with isFile() if the resource can be resolved via getFile().