# Resource folder not found when running as a jar while external folder can be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, resources

I have this problem in spring boot 1.5.1RELEASE
In my properties i have got a property config-dir. Using resource handler I can add my config folder by:

```
public PortalAppConfig(@Value("${config-dir}") String configDir) {
   this.configDir = configDir;
 }

public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
   registry
       .addResourceHandler("/assets/config/**")
       .addResourceLocations(String.format("file:%s", configDir));
 }
```

When I declare config-dir as an external folder, like `config-dir: ${user.home}/externalConfigFolder/` everything works fine.
 However I have no idea how to point path to that directory, so It could use directory from JAR file. I tried 
 `classpath:static/assets/config`, `static/assets/config` and many other variations. 
Those pictures shows directory tree for both resources and target

I know that the question sound similar to [Classpath resource not found when running as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar)
but in my case I do not want to 'use' a file inside a jar, but point to the whole directory (using path as a String) and add it to resourceHandler.
I am building project using maven. Java 8.

[image]
[image]

Comment: why do you have `file:` prepended in your java code?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources <- I was using this tutorial

Comment: The prefix `file` means it'll be looking for files in file system, and in your case relatively to your working path of the jar file. Why do you add `file` prefix, if you want to look in `classpath`?

Comment: so just .addResourceLocations(configDir); ?