# giving Freemarker resource folder in deployed application for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I'm trying to give resource folder for Freemarker template below is my bean config

```
  Configuration freeMarkerConfig() throws IOException {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29);
    cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new ClassPathResource("ftl").getFile());
    return cfg;
  }
```

and I have ftl folder in the resources folder

```
   -- java
   -- resources
       -- ftl
           -- template.ftl
```

while deploying it works fine in my local machine but fails in my docker container with exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ftl] cannot be resolved to absolute file
 path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ftl
```

I need to keep ftl in the resources folder and give the directory path to configuration. I don't know how to debug further.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue after repeated searching. Issue is because of this

[Classpath resource not found when running as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar)

Answer (score 0):

Property [`spring.freemarker.template-loader-path`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#templating-properties) is available.

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/ftl/
```

Or, use [`setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/ftl/")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.html#setTemplateLoaderPath-java.lang.String-) instead of `setDirectoryForTemplateLoading()`.

Comment: I don't see this method in freemarker.template.Configuration java class