# How to read a Json file under the resources folder?

Tags: docker, gradle, kubernetes, resources, jsonreader

In my SpringBoot application I have to read a Json file at this path src/main/resources/mock/fileName.json.
I done it in this way

```
JsonReader jsonReaderStream = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./mock/fileName.json"))));
```

It works locally but when I deploy my docker file on Kubernetes and I try to read my Json file I received a NullPointerException.
I use gradle for the build. I state that I am a beginner on gradle, docker and kubernetes.

Can anyone explain to me why it works locally but not on Kubernetes ?

Comment: what's the error you get? Is the file present on the remote location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities here.

1. Not Packaged, Not Found
2. Packaged, Not Found

Go into the `.jar` package, and check if your `mock/x.json` exists in `target\example.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes`.

If it is being packaged but not found, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar).
`new ClassPathResource("./mock/fileName.json")` and then use `resource.getInputStream()`.

---

I strongly recommend you to place these static json files under `resources/static/`, so you can directly have these files such as `resources/static/mock/a.json`, as being requested as `/mock/a.json`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to supply a file path to the method `getResourceAsStream`, but it doesn't take one. The JavaDoc isn't great and you have to piece different docs together to understand it, but here are some of the relevant parts:

> Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.
> The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.
>
> [...]
>
> In the above, the package name for a resource is
> derived from the subsequence of characters that precedes the last '/'
> in the name and then replacing each '/' character in the subsequence
> with '.'. A leading slash is ignored when deriving the package name.
> As an example, the package name derived for a resource named
> "a/b/c/foo.properties" is "a.b.c".

So to find your resource on the classpath in a running system, drop the `./` part so it just reads: `.getResourceAsStream("mock/fileName.json")`.