Classpath error when running a compiled JAR file locally
I've the following Java code in my component in which I need to access an IBM MQ using SSL/certificate.
The required keyStore file(MyKStoreFile.pfx) is present under "src/main/resources" folder in my Java project.
String myKeyStoreFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + "MyKStoreFile.pfx").getAbsolutePath();//-->line #1
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", myKeyStoreFile);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", myKeyStorePassword);


When I run this code in IntelliJ IDE, it works fine and am able to connect to the queue and send messages.
When the above code is sent to Jenkins for compilation and then pushed to cloud server using Harnes/CloudFoundry, it is working fine as well.
But when I run the compiled JAR file(using java -jar myJar.jar) locally on my windows machine, I get an error on line #1 above, saying:


"class path resource[MyKStoreFile.pfx] cannot be resolved to absolute
file path because it does not reside in the file system."

Can you please explain this behavior? Why does it work on the server and not when I manually run the compiled JAR locally?
And how do I make this work?
So far, I've tried following two approaches, but no luck:
1.myKeyStoreFile = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("MyKStoreFile.pfx").getFile();

2.ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("MyKStoreFile.pfx");
myKeyStoreFile = Paths.get(resource.getURI()).toString();

Thank you for your help!

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar

Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/780949/java/running-compiled-JAR-file-locally#3566376
